# Schema Evolution in Kinesis for python consumer and producer

Tags: python, schema, confluent-platform, amazon-kinesis

How can I have schema registry with Kinesis in python. AWS glue is in JAVA. I want similar to that in python. Can I use open source schema registry (ex:  confluent schema registry) with AWS kinesis?

Comment: have you tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/schema-registry.html ?

Comment: It supports only JAVA. I have python consumers and python producers.

Comment: They may publish a Java API, but the glue registry should have a REST API to use from anything (much like the Confluent one)